# search and count values in column of mysql result set

Tags: php, search, count

I would like to search and count unique values in a column/fieldname of a MySQL Result Set.

In other words, when some lines of one table are stored in a mysql resultset I want to know which values are stored in a specific column/fieldname of all stored lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT columnname) AS Total FROM yourtable
```

Comment: To better explain the above answer, check out the MySQL 5.1 Reference
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html